# How do I extend StackProps in cdk using Java?

Tags: java, aws-cdk

I was trying to implement something similar to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/java/index.html?software/amazon/awscdk/StackProps.html) example.

```java
 public class StackUnderTestProps extends StackProps {
     private Architecture architecture;
     public Architecture getArchitecture() {
         return this.architecture;
     }
     public StackUnderTestProps architecture(Architecture architecture) {
         this.architecture = architecture;
         return this;
     }
 }
```

I get an error with the extends because StackProps is an interface not a class. I am unable to find any examples extending StackProps using Java. Not quite sure how to do it considering that StackProps proxy is a final class. Thoughts?

Comment: you should `Implements` the StackProps not extends it

Comment: Thank you. Total mistake on my part using extends vs implements.